# Efficient Numpy 2D array construction from 1D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like this:

```
A = array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

And I am trying to get an array like this:

```
B = array([[1,2,3],
          [2,3,4],
          [3,4,5],
          [4,5,6]])
```

Where each row (of a fixed arbitrary width) is shifted by one. The array of A is 10k records long and I'm trying to find an efficient way of doing this in Numpy. Currently I am using vstack and a for loop which is slow. Is there a faster way?

Edit:

```
width = 3 # fixed arbitrary width
length = 10000 # length of A which I wish to use
B = A[0:length + 1]
for i in range (1, length):
    B = np.vstack((B, A[i, i + width + 1]))
```

Comment: Is `A` really equal to a sequence of increasing numbers or is it just for illustrating the positions? If the former, I know I quick way to do it. :)

Comment: @ianalis - just an illustration, not a sequence I'm afraid.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Actually, there's an even more efficient way to do this... The downside to using `vstack` etc, is that you're making a copy of the array.

Incidentally, this is effectively identical to @Paul's answer, but I'm posting this just to explain things in a bit more detail...

There's a way to do this with just views so that *no* memory is duplicated.

I'm directly borrowing this from [Erik Rigtorp's post to numpy-discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg29450.html), who in turn, borrowed it from Keith Goodman's [Bottleneck](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Bottleneck/0.3.0) (Which is quite useful!).

The basic trick is to directly manipulate the [strides of the array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html) (For one-dimensional arrays):

```
import numpy as np

def rolling(a, window):
    shape = (a.size - window + 1, window)
    strides = (a.itemsize, a.itemsize)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

a = np.arange(10)
print rolling(a, 3)
```

Where `a` is your input array and `window` is the length of the window that you want (3, in your case).

This yields:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]
 [3 4 5]
 [4 5 6]
 [5 6 7]
 [6 7 8]
 [7 8 9]]
```

However, there is absolutely no duplication of memory between the original `a` and the returned array.  This means that it's fast and scales *much* better than other options.

For example (using `a = np.arange(100000)` and `window=3`):

```
%timeit np.vstack([a[i:i-window] for i in xrange(window)]).T
1000 loops, best of 3: 256 us per loop

%timeit rolling(a, window)
100000 loops, best of 3: 12 us per loop
```

If we generalize this to a "rolling window" along the last axis for an N-dimensional array, we get Erik Rigtorp's "rolling window" function:

```
import numpy as np

def rolling_window(a, window):
   """
   Make an ndarray with a rolling window of the last dimension

   Parameters
   ----------
   a : array_like
       Array to add rolling window to
   window : int
       Size of rolling window

   Returns
   -------
   Array that is a view of the original array with a added dimension
   of size w.

   Examples
   --------
   >>> x=np.arange(10).reshape((2,5))
   >>> rolling_window(x, 3)
   array([[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]],
          [[5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]]])

   Calculate rolling mean of last dimension:
   >>> np.mean(rolling_window(x, 3), -1)
   array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
          [ 6.,  7.,  8.]])

   """
   if window < 1:
       raise ValueError, "`window` must be at least 1."
   if window > a.shape[-1]:
       raise ValueError, "`window` is too long."
   shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
   strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
   return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
```

So, let's look into what's going on here... Manipulating an array's `strides` may seem a bit magical, but once you understand what's going on, it's not at all.  The strides of a numpy array describe the size in bytes of the steps that must be taken to increment one value along a given axis.  So, in the case of a 1-dimensional array of 64-bit floats, the length of each item is 8 bytes, and `x.strides` is `(8,)`.

```
x = np.arange(9)
print x.strides
```

Now, if we reshape this into a 2D, 3x3 array, the strides will be `(3 * 8, 8)`, as we would have to jump 24 bytes to increment one step along the first axis, and 8 bytes to increment one step along the second axis.

```
y = x.reshape(3,3)
print y.strides
```

Similarly a transpose is the same as just reversing the strides of an array:

```
print y
y.strides = y.strides[::-1]
print y
```

Clearly, the strides of an array and the shape of an array are intimately linked.  If we change one, we have to change the other accordingly, otherwise we won't have a valid description of the memory buffer that actually holds the values of the array.

Therefore, if you want to change *both* the shape and size of an array simultaneously, you can't do it just by setting `x.strides` and `x.shape`, even if the new strides and shape are compatible.

That's where `numpy.lib.as_strided` comes in.  It's actually a very simple function that just sets the strides and shape of an array simultaneously.

It checks that the two are compatible, but not that the old strides and new shape are compatible, as would happen if you set the two independently.  (It actually does this through [numpy's `__array_interface__`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html), which allows arbitrary classes to describe a memory buffer as a numpy array.)

So, all we've done is made it so that steps one item forward (8 bytes in the case of a 64-bit array) along one axis, but *also only steps 8 bytes forward along the other axis*.

In other words, in case of a "window" size of 3, the array has a shape of `(whatever, 3)`, but instead of stepping a full `3 * x.itemsize` for the second dimension, it *only steps one item forward*, effectively making the rows of new array a "moving window" view into the original array.

(This also means that `x.shape[0] * x.shape[1]` will not be the same as `x.size` for your new array.)

At any rate, hopefully that makes things slightly clearer..

Comment: Kingston: Thanks for a really detailed answer, I learnt a lot there. I also benched your code against @eumiro's answer and your rolling answer gave me 60x speedup! Considering I plan to use this on a much larger array the speedup is incredibly useful. :)

Answer (score 11):

This solution is not efficiently implemented by a python loop since it comes with all kinds of type-checking best avoided when working with numpy arrays.  If your array is exceptionally tall, you will notice a large speed up with this:

```
newshape = (4,3)
newstrides = (A.itemsize, A.itemsize)
B = numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(A, shape=newshape, strides=newstrides)
```

This gives a *view* of the array A.  If you want a new array you can edit, do the same but with `.copy()` at the end.

Details on strides:

The `newstrides` tuple in this case will be (4,4) because the array has 4-byte items and you want to continue to step thru your data in single-item steps in the i-dimension.  The second value '4' refers to the strides in the j-dimension (in a normal 4x4 array it would be 16).  Because in this case you want to also also increment your read from the buffer in 4-byte steps in the j-dimension.

Joe give a nice, detailed description and makes things crystal-clear when he says that all this trick does is change strides and shape simultaneously.

Comment: +1 You beat me to it! I was in the middle of typing this up...  I'll still post my answer, as it goes into a bit more detail.  Also, your `strides=(4,4)` assumes that `A.itemsize` is 4 (i.e. 32-bit floats or ints).  It's best to do `strides=(A.itemsize, A.itemsize)`.

Comment: Thanks Joe.  I was looking for some on-line documentation to link to but not much out there!  This was the best I could find: http://mentat.za.net/numpy/numpy_advanced_slides/

Comment: Here we go: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html

Comment: @Paul: That helps a little, but I still can`t find the docs for numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided

Comment: @Benjamin  I doubt there is a page dedicated to it as it is not a very high-level function.  numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.__str__() shows that it only takes two arguments: shape and strides.  Shape should be obvious.  Understanding what strides are is the only tricky bit which is well-documented.

Comment: @Benjamin - It just sets the strides and shape of an array simultaneously. It's for cases where you need change both at the same time, but the new strides won't be compatible with the old shape and vice versa, so you can't just do `x.strides = new_strides` and `x.shape = new_shape`.

Comment: @Paul: Not so much of explicit Python looping in any of the answers (sofar). Could you care to elaborate more what you mean by `as they rely on a python loop`? Thanks

Comment: @eat:  I wasn't referring to your answer, only the OP's and the selected answer.  Both of which have a `for` in the code.  (A list comprehension is still a python loop.)

Answer (score 2):

Which approach are you using?

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
width = 3

np.vstack([A[i:i-len(A)+width] for i in xrange(len(A)-width)])
# needs 26.3µs

np.vstack([A[i:i-width] for i in xrange(width)]).T
# needs 13.2µs
```

If your width is relatively low (3) and you have a big `A` (10000 elements), then the difference is even more important: 32.4ms for the first and 44µs for the second.

Answer (score 2):

Just to further go with the answer of @Joe general

```
import numpy as np
def rolling(a, window):
    step = 2 
    shape = ( (a.size-window)/step + 1   , window)


    strides = (a.itemsize*step, a.itemsize)

    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

a = np.arange(10)

print rolling(a, 3)
```

which outputs:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [2 3 4]
 [4 5 6]
 [6 7 8]]
```

To generalize further for the 2d case,i.e use it for patch extraction from an image

```
def rolling2d(a,win_h,win_w,step_h,step_w):

    h,w = a.shape
    shape = ( ((h-win_h)/step_h + 1)  * ((w-win_w)/step_w + 1) , win_h , win_w)

    strides = (step_w*a.itemsize, h*a.itemsize,a.itemsize)


    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

a = np.arange(36).reshape(6,6)
print a
print rolling2d (a,3,3,2,2)
```

which outputs:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35]]
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 6  7  8]
  [12 13 14]]

 [[ 2  3  4]
  [ 8  9 10]
  [14 15 16]]

 [[ 4  5  6]
  [10 11 12]
  [16 17 18]]

 [[ 6  7  8]
  [12 13 14]
  [18 19 20]]]
```

Comment: Is it possible in the above example to not pull results that wrap around the right edge of the original array. for example, the third output 
`[4,5,6;
10,11,12;
16,17,18]` 
'wraps' back around. For image processing I'd like to avoid this and simply skip to the next returned result.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be faster than looping, when the width is fixed at a low number...

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
b = numpy.reshape(a, (numpy.shape(a)[0],1))
b = numpy.concatenate((b, numpy.roll(b,-1,0), numpy.roll(b,-2,0)), 1)
b = b[0:(numpy.shape(a)[0]/2) + 1,:]
```

EDIT Clearly, the solutions using strides are superior to this, with the only major disadvantage being that they are not yet well documented...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a more generalized function similar to that of @JustInTime but applicable to `ndarray`

```
def sliding_window(x, size, overlap=0):
    step = size - overlap # in npts
    nwin = (x.shape[-1]-size)//step + 1
    shape = x.shape[:-1] + (nwin, size)
    strides = x.strides[:-1] + (step*x.strides[-1], x.strides[-1])
    return stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=shape, strides=strides)
```

An example,

```
x = np.arange(10)
M.sliding_window(x, 5, 3)
Out[1]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])


x = np.arange(10).reshape((2,5))
M.sliding_window(x, 3, 1)
Out[2]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [2, 3, 4]],

       [[5, 6, 7],
        [7, 8, 9]]])
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Note that this truncates the last row if the windows don't exactly match up (in your first example, it loses the row that should contain '9').  But If you change the "nwin" line to `nwin = int(np.ceil((x.shape[-1]-size)/step + 1))`, it would seem that it will then pad the result with zeros.   (Kinda surprised this doesn't give some seg fault, but I guess it's built in to `stride_tricks`.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at: [view_as_windows](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.10.x/api/skimage.util.html#view-as-windows).

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows
window_shape = (4, )
aa = np.arange(1000000000) # 1 billion
bb = view_as_windows(aa, window_shape)
```

Around 1 second.