# Apply function to 3 elements at a time in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to apply a function to a monodimensional array 3 elements at a time, and output for each of them a single element.

for example I have an array of 13 elements:

```
a = np.arange(13)**2
```

and I want to apply a function, let's say np.std as an example.

Here is the equivalent list comprehension:

```
[np.std(a[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(a),3)] 
[1.6996731711975948,
 6.5489609014628334,
 11.440668201153674,
 16.336734339790461,
 0.0]
```

does anyone know a more efficient way using numpy functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to reshape it and apply the function along an axis.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(12)**2
b = a.reshape(4,3)
print np.std(b, axis=1)
```

<strike>If you need a little better performance than that,</strike> you could try [stride_tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936620/using-strides-for-an-efficient-moving-average-filter).  Below is the same as above except using stride_tricks.  I was wrong about the performance gain, because as you can see below, `b` becomes exactly the same view as `b` above.  I wouldn't be surprised if they compiled to exactly the same thing.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(12)**2
b = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(4,3), strides=(a.itemsize*3, a.itemsize))
print np.std(b, axis=1)
```

Comment: Stride tricks is what I was looking for, would you have an example for this case? It looks pretty complex to use

Comment: @Andrea Z:  See my update.  What `as_strided` allows you to do is to change the shape and the strides at the same time, allowing a change in the apparent size of the array.  Since you don't need to change the strides or the size in this case, it is exactly equivalent to using `reshape`.  See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923617/efficient-numpy-2d-array-construction-from-1d-array post for more explanation.

Comment: and if the function you want to use doesn't have an `axis=` parameter, use [numpy.apply_along_axis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about something like vectorize? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape it. But that does require that the size not change. If you can tack on some bogus entries at the end you can do this:

```
[np.std(s) for s in a.reshape(-1,3)]
```

Comment: What you mean with `If you can tack on some bogus entries ...`? I don't think that's possible with `reshape`, but with `stride tricks` that's easily the case.

Comment: You can't reshape with partial rows resulting. To make it rectangular some might have to be added. But striding is better in that case.