# numpy tensordot related issue

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have a specific issue with multiplying matrices in numpy.
Here is an example:

```
P=np.arange(30).reshape((-1,3))
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
   [ 3,  4,  5],
   [ 6,  7,  8],
   [ 9, 10, 11],
   [12, 13, 14],
   [15, 16, 17],
   [18, 19, 20],
   [21, 22, 23],
   [24, 25, 26],
   [27, 28, 29]])
```

I want to multiply each row by its transpose in order to obtain a 3x3 matrix for each row,
for example for the first row:

```
P[0]*P[0][:,np.newaxis]
array([[0, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 2],
   [0, 2, 4]])
```

and store the result in a 3-d matrix M:

```
M=np.zeros((10,3,3))
for i in range(10):
    M[i] = P[i]*P[i][:,np.newaxis]
```

I think there might be a way to do this without looping, maybe with tensor-dot, but cannot find it.

Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just simple like this:

```
In []: P= arange(30).reshape(-1, 3)
In []: P[:, :, None]* P[:, None, :]
Out[]:
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   1,   2],
        [  0,   2,   4]],
       [[  9,  12,  15],
        [ 12,  16,  20],
        [ 15,  20,  25]],
       [[ 36,  42,  48],
        [ 42,  49,  56],
        [ 48,  56,  64]],
       #...   
       [[729, 756, 783],
        [756, 784, 812],
        [783, 812, 841]]])    
In []: P[1]* P[1][:, None]
Out[]:
array([[ 9, 12, 15],
       [12, 16, 20],
       [15, 20, 25]])
```

Comment: great, exactly what I was looking for, is there an easy methodology to understand which index I should expand with None?

Comment: @Andrea Z: For such methodology; I'll first try to figure out how the `numpy` broadcasting really works. Then just realizing you are looking for a `shape= (10, 3, 3)´, it would be more or less 'natural' to figure out that `(P[:, :, None]* P[:, None, :]).shape== (10, 3, 3)`. Perhaps not a best description, but the main point I stand for is; familiarize your self how broadcasting works. Now feel free to ask an other question on 'the innards of broadcasting'! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since I like stride_tricks, that's what I'd use.  I'm sure there are other ways.

Change the stride and shape of the array so that you expand it into 3D.  You could easily do the same thing with the "transposed" version of P, but here I just reshape it and let the broadcasting rules stretch it into the other dimension.

```
P=np.arange(30).reshape((-1,3))
astd = numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
its = P.itemsize
M = astd(P,(10,3,3),(its*3,its,0))*P.reshape((10,1,3))
```

I'm going to add a reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923617/efficient-numpy-2d-array-construction-from-1d-array) because it is a nice detailed explanation of `stride_tricks.as_strided`.

Comment: +1 stride_tricks is really wonderful, but so complex to grasp!

Answer (score 0):

This partially solves the problem using `tensordot()`,

```
from numpy import arange,tensordot

P = arange(30).reshape((-1,3))

i = 3

T = tensordot(P,P,0)[:,:,i,:]

print T[i]
print tensordot(P[i],P[i],0)
```

`T` contains all the products you want (and more), it's just a question of extracting them.

Comment: Although OP speculated the possibility to utilize `tensordot(.)`, nothing in his code actually requires it. Your solution seems to be very expensive both execution time and memory consumption wise. Have you made any benchmarks to compare yours solution with the other ones? Thanks

Comment: @eat: True, it is expensive memory wise. In this example, with a 10 by 3 array, execution time is approximately double using `tensordot()`. It gets progressively worse as the array size increases.

Comment: I didn't make the point explicitly, but tensordot is probably _not_ the way to do it, for a completely different reason. If you view `P` as a rank-2 tensor then only three options exist for the product of `P` with itself, 1) either all the indexes cancel leaving you with a rank-0 tensor (a scalar), 2) 1 set of indexes cancels and you are left with a rank-2 tensor (a matrix), or 3) none of them cancel and you're left with a rank-4 tensor. The OP wanted a rank-3 tensor as an answer, which `tensordot()` won't give you, unless you slice the rank-4 product.