# nditer: possible to manually handle dimensions with different lengths?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Using numpy's [nditer](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html), is it possible to manually handle dimensions with different
lengths?

For example, lets say I had an array A[5, 100] and I wanted to sample every
10 along the second axis so I would end up with an array B[5,10]. Is it
possible to do this with nditer, handling the iteration over the second axis
manually of course (probably in cython)?

Another way to ask this would be, is it possible to ask nditer to allow me to manually iterate over a set of dimensions I provide?

I want to be able to do something like this (modified from this [example](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#putting-the-inner-loop-in-cython))

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
def sum_squares_cy(arr):
    cdef np.ndarray[double] x
    cdef np.ndarray[double] y
    cdef int size
    cdef double value
    cdef int j

    axeslist = list(arr.shape)
    axeslist[1] = -1

    out = zeros((arr.shape[0], 10))
    it = np.nditer([arr, out], flags=['reduce_ok', 'external_loop',
                                      'buffered', 'delay_bufalloc'],
                op_flags=[['readonly'], ['readwrite', 'no_broadcast']],
                op_axes=[None, axeslist],
                op_dtypes=['float64', 'float64'])
    it.operands[1][...] = 0
    it.reset()
    for xarr, yarr in it:
        x = xarr
        y = yarr
        size = x.shape[0]
        j = 0
        for i in range(size):
           #some magic here involving indexing into x[i] and y[j]
    return it.operands[1]
```

Does this make sense? Is it possible to do?

Comment: Strides... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923617/efficient-numpy-2d-array-construction-from-1d-array

Answer (score 0):

```
a = numpy.arange(500.0).reshape((5,100))
numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (5,10), (6400,64))
```