# How to calculate the correlation coefficient on a rolling window of a vector using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, correlation, rolling-computation

I'm able to calculate a rolling correlation coefficient for a 1D-array (data against `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`) using a loop.
I'm looking for a smarter solution using `numpy` **(not `pandas`)**.
Here is my current code:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([10,5,8,9,15,22,26,11,15,16,18,7,4,8,-2,-3,-4,-6,-2,0,10,0,5,8])
x = np.zeros_like(data).astype('float32')
length = 5
for i in range(length, data.shape[0]):
    x[i] = np.corrcoef(data[i - length:i], np.arange(length))[0, 1]
print(x)
```

x gives :

```
    [ 0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.607  0.959  0.98   0.328 -0.287
 -0.61  -0.314 -0.18  -0.8   -0.782 -0.847 -0.811 -0.825 -0.869 -0.283
  0.566  0.863  0.643  0.454]
```

Any solution without the loop please?

Comment: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html

Comment: FYI I added some results from timing all the solutions here to [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75072873/843953). I was quite surprised by the results for larger inputs.

Comment: Thank you Pranav Hosangadi, a real complete job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) (available in numpy v1.20.0+)

```
swindow = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(data, (length,))
```

which gives a view on the `data` array that looks like so:

```
array([[10,  5,  8,  9, 15],
       [ 5,  8,  9, 15, 22],
       [ 8,  9, 15, 22, 26],
       [ 9, 15, 22, 26, 11],
       [15, 22, 26, 11, 15],
       [22, 26, 11, 15, 16],
       [26, 11, 15, 16, 18],
       [11, 15, 16, 18,  7],
       [15, 16, 18,  7,  4],
       [16, 18,  7,  4,  8],
       [18,  7,  4,  8, -2],
       [ 7,  4,  8, -2, -3],
       [ 4,  8, -2, -3, -4],
       [ 8, -2, -3, -4, -6],
       [-2, -3, -4, -6, -2],
       [-3, -4, -6, -2,  0],
       [-4, -6, -2,  0, 10],
       [-6, -2,  0, 10,  0],
       [-2,  0, 10,  0,  5],
       [ 0, 10,  0,  5,  8]])
```

Now, we want to apply the correlation coefficient calculation to each row of this array. Unfortunately, [`np.corrcoef`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) doesn't take an `axis` argument, it applies the calculation to the *entire* matrix and doesn't provide a way to do so for each row/column.

However, the calculation for the correlation coefficient of two vectors is quite simple:

[image: linear correlation coefficient]

Applying that here:

```
def vec_corrcoef(X, y, axis=1):
    Xm = np.mean(X, axis=axis, keepdims=True)
    ym = np.mean(y)
    n = np.sum((X - Xm) * (y - ym), axis=axis)
    d = np.sqrt(np.sum((X - Xm)**2, axis=axis) * np.sum((y - ym)**2))
    return n / d
```

Now, call this function with our array and `arange`:

```
cc = vec_corrcoef(swindow, np.arange(length))
```

which gives the desired result:

```
array([ 0.60697698,  0.95894955,  0.98      ,  0.3279521 , -0.28709766,
       -0.61035663, -0.31390158, -0.17995394, -0.80041656, -0.78192905,
       -0.84702587, -0.81091772, -0.82464375, -0.86892667, -0.28347335,
        0.56568542,  0.86304424,  0.64326752,  0.45374261,  0.38135638])
```

To get your `x`, just set the appropriate indices of a `zeros` array of the correct size.

**Note:** I think your `x` should contain nonzero values starting at the `4` index (because that's where the sliding window is full) instead of starting at index `5`.

```
x = np.zeros(data.shape)
x[-len(cc):] = cc
```

If you are sure that your values should start at the index `5`, then you can do:

```
x = np.zeros(data.shape)
x[length:] = cc[:-1] # Ignore the last value in cc
```

---

Comparing the runtimes of your original approach with those suggested in the answers here:

- `f_OP_loopy` is your approach, which implements a sliding window using a loop
- `f_PH_numpy` is my approach, which uses the `sliding_window_view` and the vectorized function for row-wise calculation of the vector correlation coefficient
- `f_RA_numpy` is [Rontogiannis's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75072699/843953), which tiles the `arange`, calculates the correlation coefficient for the entire matrices, and only selects the first `len(data) - length` rows of the last column
- `f_RA_recur` is Rontogiannis's recursive approach, but I didn't time this because it misses out on the last correlation coefficient.

[image: Timing plot]

1. Unsurprisingly, the numpy-only solution is faster than the loopy approach.
2. My numpy solution, which computes the row-wise correlation coefficient, is faster than that shown by [Rontogiannis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75072699/843953) below, because the extra work involved in tiling the vector input and calculating the correlation of the *entire matrix*, only to discard the unwanted elements, is avoided by my approach.
3. As the input data size increases, this "extra work" in Rontogiannis's approach increases so much that its runtime is *worse even than the loopy approach!* I am unsure if this extra time is in  the `np.corrcoef` calculation or in the `np.tile` operation.

<sup>Note: This plot was obtained on my 2.2GHz i7 Macbook Air with 8GB RAM, Python 3.10.7 and numpy 1.23.3. Similar results were obtained on Google Colab</sup>

[image]

If you're interested in the timing code, here it is:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def time_funcs(funcs, sizes, arg_gen, N=20):
    times = np.zeros((len(sizes), len(funcs)))
    gdict = globals().copy()
    for i, s in enumerate(sizes):
        args = arg_gen(s)
        print(args)
        for j, f in enumerate(funcs):
            gdict.update(locals())
            try:
                times[i, j] = timeit.timeit("f(*args)", globals=gdict, number=N) / N
                print(f"{i}/{len(sizes)}, {j}/{len(funcs)}, {times[i, j]}")
            except ValueError:
                print(f"ERROR in {f}, with args=", *args)
                
            
    return times

def plot_times(times, funcs):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for j, f in enumerate(funcs):
        ax.plot(sizes, times[:, j], label=f.__name__)
    
    
    ax.set_xlabel("Array size")
    ax.set_ylabel("Time per function call (s)")
    ax.set_xscale("log")
    ax.set_yscale("log")
    ax.legend()
    ax.grid()
    fig.tight_layout()
    return fig, ax

#%%
def arg_gen(n):
    return [np.random.randint(-100, 100, (n,)), 5]
    
#%%
def f_OP_loopy(data, length):
    x = np.zeros_like(data).astype('float32')
    for i in range(length-1, data.shape[0]):
        x[i] = np.corrcoef(data[i - length + 1:i+1], np.arange(length))[0, 1]
    return x
    

def f_PH_numpy(data, length):    
    swindow = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(data, (length,))
    cc = vec_corrcoef(swindow, np.arange(length))
    x = np.zeros(data.shape)
    x[-len(cc):] = cc
    return x

def f_RA_recur(data, length):
    return np.concatenate((
        np.zeros([length,]),
        rolling_correlation_recurse(data, 0, length)
    ))

def f_RA_numpy(data, length):
    n = len(data)
    cc = np.corrcoef(np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(data, length), np.tile(np.arange(length), (n-length+1, 1)))[:n-length+1, -1]
    x = np.zeros(data.shape)
    x[-len(cc):] = cc
    return x
#%%

def rolling_correlation_recurse(data, i, length) :
    assert i+length < data.size
    left = np.array([np.corrcoef(data[i:i+length], np.arange(length))[0, 1]])
    if i+length+1 == data.size :
        return left
    right = rolling_correlation_recurse(data, i+1, length)
    return np.concatenate((left, right))

def vec_corrcoef(X, y, axis=1):
    Xm = np.mean(X, axis=axis, keepdims=True)
    ym = np.mean(y)
    n = np.sum((X - Xm) * (y - ym), axis=axis)
    d = np.sqrt(np.sum((X - Xm)**2, axis=axis) * np.sum((y - ym)**2))
    return n / d

#%% 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #%% Set up sim
    sizes = [5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10_000] #, 50_000, 100_000]
    funcs = [f_OP_loopy, #f_RA_recur,
             f_PH_numpy, f_RA_numpy]
    
    
    #%% Run timing
    time_fcalls = np.zeros((len(sizes), len(funcs))) * np.nan
    time_fcalls = time_funcs(funcs, sizes, arg_gen)
    
    fig, ax = plot_times(time_fcalls, funcs)
    ax.set_xlabel(f"Input size")

    plt.show()
    input("Enter x to exit")
```

Comment: Very clear solution and I appreciated the explanation (really helpfull). Thank you for the index correction (you are right with 4).

Answer (score 1):

Ask and you shall receive. Here is a solution that uses recursion:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([10,5,8,9,15,22,26,11,15,16,18,7,4,8,-2,-3,-4,-6,-2,0,10,0,5,8])
length = 5

def rolling_correlation_recurse(data, i, length) :
    assert i+length < data.size
    left = np.array([np.corrcoef(data[i:i+length], np.arange(length))[0, 1]])
    if i+length+1 == data.size :
        return left
    right = rolling_correlation_recurse(data, i+1, length)
    return np.concatenate((left, right))

def rolling_correlation(data, length) :
    return np.concatenate((
        np.zeros([length,]),
        rolling_correlation_recurse(data, 0, length)
    ))

print(rolling_correlation(data, length))
```

Edit: here is a numpy solution too:

```
n = len(data)
print(np.corrcoef(np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(data, length), np.tile(np.arange(length), (n-length+1, 1)))[:n-length+1, -1])
```

Comment: The "edit solution" for a numpy approach is a very nice one, it works, thank you

Comment: Note: a +1 was missing in the given formula as the last correlation number dropped. Here it is corrected (for any other user):
np.corrcoef(np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(data, length), np.tile(np.arange(length), (n-length+1, 1)))[:n-length+1, -1]

Comment: @tibibou good point, fixed it

Answer (score 1):

@pho 's answer is very good, but in my use case the performance is still not satisfactory. The main concern is that the calculation of squared sum of sliding window is still done separately for each window. When calculating the squared sum of the next sliding window. Instinctively one can simply subtract the earlist element and add the latest element.

Therefore I tried to find sliding window operators and I get inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419871/improving-code-efficiency-standard-deviation-on-sliding-windows). The rough idea is to expand the pearson's correlation coefficient formula and use efficient moving-window operators to replace the sums.

Let's start with the formula of Pearson's Correlation Coefficient:
[image: formula PCC]

The nominator can be rewritten as follow:
[image: nominator]

In the denominator, the standard deviation of y is only calculated once. The calculation of sliding window standard deviation of x can be rewritten as:
[image: std]

After those conversion, the sliding window calculation falls in three terms: Convolution of X and y, mean of X squared and mean of x. Convolution can be efficiently done by `np.correlate(X,y)`. The other two can be done using `scipy.ndimage.filters.uniform_filter`, please refer to the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419871/improving-code-efficiency-standard-deviation-on-sliding-windows).

The resulting code is shown below:

```py
    from scipy.ndimage.filters import uniform_filter1d
    import numpy as np

    def window_corrcoef(arr1, arr2):
        length = len(arr2) # window size
        # Calculate the slicing index
        start_slice = length // 2
        end_slice = -(length - start_slice - 1)
        if end_slice == 0:
            end_slice = None
        # sliding window mean and squared mean of arr1
        c1 = uniform_filter1d(arr1, length, mode='constant')[start_slice:end_slice]
        c2 = uniform_filter1d(arr1 * arr1, length, mode='constant')[start_slice:end_slice]
        Xstd = np.sqrt(c2 - c1 * c1)
        # mean and std of arr2 will only be calculated once
        n = np.correlate(arr1, arr2) / length - c1 * np.mean(arr2)
        d = Xstd * np.std(arr2)
        return n / d
```

The code might not be perfect as I assume that the length of `arr2` should be less than `arr1`. The function `uniform_filter1d` will output array with the same size of input. Therefore it needs slicing. The slicing code takes care of both odd and even size of `arr2` but it is a bit messy. Maybe there is a cleverer way to be done.

For performance comparison I stole the code from [@pho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843953/pho). My approach is labelled as `f_sj_scipy`. Actually in my use case where the length of arr1 is around 60k, the length of arr2 is around 20k. The difference could be as large as 10x.

[image: performance]